# what is the `&|` operator and where does it come from?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

About halfway down [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Restrictions) there is a "Restrictions" section which states: "New operators such as `**`, `<>`, or `&|` cannot be created".

I know that `**` is the exponentiation operator from python, and I know that `<>` is the "spaceship" (compareTo) operator from PHP. What on earth is `&|`?

correction `<=>` is the "spaceship", `<>` is a common substitute for `!=`

Comment: It's an example of an operator that cannot be created.

Comment: C++ is not Python or PHP. The syntax for those operators is simply not allowed, has nothing to do with exponentiation or comparison. In C++ you can replace the normal function of an operator by overloading but you can't create new operator syntax, that's all it means. Just to clarify, there is nothing special about `**`, `<>`, or `&|`, they are examples of invalid syntax

Comment: I guess I just assumed that given that `**` and `<>` are real operators in other languages, that `&|` might be as well. But that does not seem unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the page is trying to say is that you can't create operators in C++ that doesn't already exist as operators. In other words, `<>` is not an operator in C++ today, so you can't do `T operator<>(U x, U y)` to define what this operator does. It's an invalid combination. Likewise for the other "symbols" listed. C++ defines a given set of operators, `+`, `-`, `%`, `/`, `*`, `<<`, `>>` and many more. These are allowed to override (with user-defined types). But the language does not allow the programmer to invent his/her own symbols and making them into operators.

This helps the parsing of the code by having a fixed set of operators that are lexically well-defined. That's aside from the confusions that this would cause when you read

```
 if (x <&^> y) ...
```

or

```
 x = y +- 11;
```

[What the heck is `<&^>` or `+-` supposed to mean?]

Sure, it's also possible to cause confusion with the existing operators, but it's at least somewhat less confusing than the programmer making up his/her own versions and variants.

The fact that some other language does have meanings for other symbols is up to those languages. Until the symbol is available in C++ (and some new operators are introduced at times, although quite rarely), they are not valid as C++ operators.

Comment: seems reasonable, but is it just me or would it be kinda cool if you could?

Answer (score 0):

The only usage of &| is called: bit wise operators..
It's not used in a programming language, but to express something..like: I want to know if the result and/or (&|) matches something..

Comment: There is no `&|` operator. There is bit-wise AND which is `&` and bit-wise OR which is `|`. Writing `&|` is invalid syntax

Comment: exactly!! that's what I've said.. I said that you use it as a slang.. not a coding operator